# How to ask for user input in R in an online IDE?

Tags: r, input, ide, user-input, stdin

I'm preparing an online tutorial page that does code evaluation using pre-fed tests. I'm trying to write a simple program in an online ide environment and `readline(prompt="")` does not work.

Can anyone suggest what needs to be modified for online environment?
link to online code: jdoodle.com/a/PzU

for reference: code is

```
x <- 10
y <- 25
z <- sum(x,y)
p <- readline(prompt="enter val:")
cat("x + y = ", z)
cat(p)
cat("\nterminate")
```

output is:

```
enter val:
x + y =  35
terminate
```

desired output:

```
enter val:
[reads input value: "3"]
x + y =  35
3
terminate
```

Comment: While this is not the tech support forum for "jdoodle", that page has a "Stdin Inputs" box. That's where each entry can be pre-entered, but you aren't going to get an interactive experience on that site for any code.

Comment: @hrbrmstr doesn't appear to work even after turning interactive session on (there's a button for it). It would probably be best to contact their support on what's going on.

Comment: "Interactive" mode has nothing to do with enabling the functionality you're looking for. That just enables line-by-line execution of code with the proper keystrokes. You will not be able to do what you want on that service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about specific functionality of a third-party website and has nothing to do with programming in R